# Why would this code cause: ArgumentError comparison of Array with Array failed

Tags: ruby, sorting, enumerable

Ruby beginner here. Came across this question recently:

*My friend John and I are members of the "Fat to Fit Club (FFC)". John is worried because each month a list with the weights of members is published and each month he is the last on the list which means he is the heaviest.
I am the one who establishes the list so I told him: "Don't worry any more, I will modify the order of the list". It was decided to attribute a "weight" to numbers. The weight of a number will be from now on the sum of its digits.
For example 99 will have "weight" 18, 100 will have "weight" 1 so in the list 100 will come before 99. Given a string with the weights of FFC members in normal order can you give this string ordered by "weights" of these numbers?*

I attempted to solve this with:

```
def order_weight(strng)
  new_strng = strng.split(" ").map! {|x| x.split(//)}.map! {|x| x.reduce {|sum, input| sum.to_i + input.to_i}}
  output = strng.split(" ").zip(new_strng)
  output.sort_by! {|x, y| [y, x]}
  output.reduce("") {|memo, input| memo << input[0] + " "}.chop
end

order_weight("2000 10003 1234000 44444444 9999 11 11 22 123") 
#=> "11 11 2000 10003 22 123 1234000 44444444 9999"
```

This seems to work fine (if there's a simpler way please let me know) but my issue is that i recieve:
`#<ArgumentError: comparison of Array with Array failed>`

I've read around a little and I saw that this issue can be caused by comparing nil values with Enumerable#sort_by but as far as i'm aware this shouldn't be the case here(?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Whenever you report an exception please include the line on which it was raised. You need to also show what `string` looks like.

Comment: I guess another piece of info I should have included is that i only get this error while entering my code through the website that these questions come from (codewars). Here's an image to show what i mean http://imgur.com/a/aqRkP.

Comment: Don't forget there's an edit button at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the weights by member are as follows.

```
weights = { "Bubba"=>302, "Phil"=>139, "Hubert"=>280 }
```

Then you can do the following.

```
puts weights.sort_by { |k,v| v.to_s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,s| t+s.to_i } }.
  map { |a| a.join(" ") }.
  join("\n")
  # Bubba 302
  # Hubert 280
  # Phil 139
```

The steps are as follows.

```
a = weights.sort_by { |k,v| v.to_s.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,s| t+s.to_i } }
  #=> [["Bubba", 302], ["Hubert", 280], ["Phil", 139]] 
b = a.map { |a| a.join(" ") }
  #=> ["Bubba 302", "Hubert 280", "Phil 139"] 
c = b.join("\n")
  #=> "Bubba 302\nHubert 280\nPhil 139" 
puts c
  # Bubba 302
  # Hubert 280
  # Phil 139
```

In calculating `a` we have

```
enum = weights.sort_by
  #=> #<Enumerator: {"Bubba"=>302, "Phil"=>139, "Hubert"=>280}:sort_by>
```

The first element generated by `enum` is passed to the block and assigned to the block variables using *parallel assignment*.

```
k, v = enum.next
  #=> ["Bubba", 302] 
k #=> "Bubba"
v #=> 302
```

The block calculation is as follows.

```
d = v.to_s
  # => "302" 
d.each_char.reduce(0) { |t,s| t+s.to_i }
  #=> 5
```

The calculations for the remaining two elements of `enum` are similar.